# How to establish user control in Oracle?

Tags: linux, oracle, server

I need to grant privileges to some user and establish control over him. How should I do it?
All I know is that this is possibly audit-related. Where to read about this, and what is the best command to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
audit alter user by some_user by access;
```

You can learn more about this command here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4003.htm

Comment: Thank you. That is, we have granted the ALTER USER privilege to the user. And how to establish control itself? Is the use of this command user control?

Comment: What do you mean by "control"? If they have `ALTER USER` privilege, then all you can do is revoke the privilege; you can't control how it is used. Some additional control is possible if you have deployed/configured Database Vault, but that is an extra-cost option of Oracle Enterprise Edition only.

Comment: auditing is not "control" - it will keep a record of what the user does, but it doesn't stop them from doing it (e.g. altering the *wrong* user).